# how to perform character concatenation in java

Tags: java

```
String st="java is awesome";
   char[] ch=st.toCharArray();
    st="";
    for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
    {
        if(ch[i]!='a')
            st=st+ch[i];
        else if(ch[i]=='a')
            st=st+ch[i]+'#';
    }
    System.out.println(st);
```

i have to perform character concatenation without using '+'.Is it possible?

Comment: [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question)

Answer (score 1):

The best practice to deal with string concatenations is to use `StringBuilder` as shown below:

```
            String st="java is awesome";
            char[] ch=st.toCharArray();
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++) {
                if(ch[i] != 'a')
                    builder.append(ch[i]);
                else if(ch[i]=='a')
                    builder.append(ch[i]).append('#');
            }
            System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Comment: without using any built-in methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.valueOf() and st.concat() method like this

```
    String st="java is awesome";
    char[] ch=st.toCharArray();
    st="";
    for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
    {
        if(ch[i]!='a')
            st=st.concat(String.valueOf(ch[i]));
        else if(ch[i]=='a')
            st=st.concat(String.valueOf(ch[i])).concat(String.valueOf('#'));
    }
    System.out.println(st);
```